# How to send values from the spreadsheet to a user interface created using HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

Good Morning,

I created a html form to change values from a google spreadsheet.
I was able to do the trick, but I want the form to be pre-filed with some values from the spreadsheet.
I have no idea on how to do that.
I don't have much experience in programming, so I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

**Here is the code I'm using**

GS file:

```
    function editDadosPessoais() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
        html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('DadosPessoais')
    ss.show(html);
}
```

HTML file:

```
 <html>
     <head>
      <meta content="Sheets" name="generator" />
       <style type="text/css"><!--br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
       .auto-style3 {
        font-family: Calibri;
       }
       .auto-style4 {
        font-family: Calibri;
        text-decoration: underline;
       }
       .auto-style5 {
        text-decoration: underline;
       }
       --></style>
      <meta content="pt-br" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
      <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
      <title>Untitled 1</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <form name="DadosPessoais" action="" method="post" style="width: 473px; height: 454px" onsubmit="formSubmit(this)">
        <strong><span class="auto-style4">NOME:</span></strong><span class="auto-style3"><strong>&nbsp;
        </strong></span><strong>
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Name1" id="Name1" style="width: 382px" type="text"/><br />
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style3"><span class="auto-style5">CÓDIGO DEPENDENTE:</span>
        </span><select class="auto-style3" name="Dep1" id="Dep1" style="width: 76px">
        <option>Titular</option>
        <option>Esposo(a)</option>
        <option>Filho(a)</option>
        <option>Outro(a)</option>
        </select><br />
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style3"><span class="auto-style5">TELEFONES:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="auto-style5">SITUAÇÃO: </span></span>
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Tel1" id="Tel1" type="text"/><span class="auto-style3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span><select class="auto-style3" name="SitTel1" id="SitTel1" style="width: 97px">
        <option></option>
        <option>CORRETO</option>
        <option>ERRADO</option>
        </select><br class="auto-style3" />
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Tel2" id="Tel2" type="text"/><span class="auto-style3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span><select class="auto-style3" name="SitTel2" id="SitTel2" style="width: 97px">
        <option></option>
        <option>CORRETO</option>
        <option>ERRADO</option>
        </select><br class="auto-style3" />
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Tel3" id="Tel3" type="text" /><span class="auto-style3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span><select class="auto-style3" name="SitTel3" id="SitTel3" style="width: 97px">
        <option></option>
        <option>CORRETO</option>
        <option>ERRADO</option>
        </select><br />
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style3"><span class="auto-style5">EMAIL:</span> </span>
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Email1" id="Email1" style="width: 329px" type="text" /><br />
        <br class="auto-style3" />
        <span class="auto-style4">ENDEREÇO:<br />
        </span><br class="auto-style4" />
        <span class="auto-style3">Logradouro: </span>
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Log1" id="Log1" style="width: 271px" type="text" /><span class="auto-style3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        nº: </span>
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Number1" id="Number1" style="width: 59px" type="text" /><span class="auto-style3"><br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br />
        Complemento: </span>
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Comp1" id="Comp1" style="width: 91px" type="text" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="auto-style3">Bairro: </span>
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Bairro1" id="Bairro1" style="width: 197px" type="text" /><span class="auto-style3">
        <br />&nbsp;&nbsp; <br />
        Cidade: </span>
        <input class="auto-style3" name="Cid1" id="Cid1" style="width: 276px" type="text" /><span class="auto-style3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        Estado: </span>
        <select class="auto-style3" name="Estado1" id="Estado1" style="width: 55px">
        <option></option><option>AC</option><option>AL</option><option>AP</option><option>AM</option><option>BA</option><option>CE</option><option>DF</option><option>ES</option><option>GO</option><option>MA</option><option>MG</option><option>MS</option><option>MT</option><option>PA</option><option>PB</option><option>PE</option><option>PI</option><option>PR</option><option>RJ</option><option>RN</option><option>RO</option><option>RR</option><option>RS</option><option>SC</option><option>SE</option><option>SP</option><option>TO</option>
        </select><br class="auto-style3" />
        <br class="auto-style3" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <div>
       <input type="submit" class="button redButton" value="Submit">
       </div>
      </form>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       function formSubmit(argTheFormElement) {
        google.script.run
         .withFailureHandler(myFailureFunction)
         .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
         .getValuesFromForm(argTheFormElement);
        }
       function myFailureFunction(argError) {
        alert("There was an error: " + argError.message);
        google.script.host.close();
        }
      </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Documentation: [Serving templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates). One potential pitfall is that the getActiveSpreadsheet method won't work in the doGet function serving the HTML; you'll need to access the spreadsheet with openById or openByUrl method.

Comment: Is your form in a sidebar, or a dialog box, or a web app?  Or even something that is not a Google product?

Comment: My form is in a Dialog box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a scriptlet into the value attribute setting of the input field.

Currently:

```
<input class="auto-style3" name="Name1" id="Name1" style="width: 382px" type="text"/>
```

Should be:

```
<input class="auto-style3" name="Name1" id="Name1" 
  style="width: 382px" type="text" value="<?!= theFunctionNameHere() ?>"/>
```

Server Code:

```
function theFunctionNameHere() {
  return "testing";
};
```

The function to display the dialog box must have `createTemplateFromFile().evaluate()`

```
function editDadosPessoais() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('the_HTML_file_name')
    .evaluate()
    .setWidth(640).setHeight(460)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Input Form');
};
```

Comment: As I said I don't have much experience in programming. I tried it, but it didn't work. The pre filled value of the form became <?!= theFunctionNameHere() ?>. Other problem is the doGet() function, When I tried to use that the form didn't appear anymore. It shows Finished Script without showing the form.

Comment: You don't need a `doGet()` function, that's for a Web App.  I updated the answer for a dialog box.  Let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you want to do a couple simple steps.

A) Make your HTML Page with an empty tag with an id of your choice.

```
<div id='custom> </div>
```

B) In your script tag, make a function that triggers when it opens, AKA don't wrap it as a function.

```
<script>
  google.script.run ...
</script>
```

This will launch automatically, because it has no function container.

C) Then make your google.script.run function in your .gs file to return the default values you want. And run it in your script with a success handler, that points the returned data to your html tag.

```
<script>
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler( function(returnedData) {
       document.getElementById('customId').innerHTML = returnedData;
    })
  .yourCustomGSFunction();
</script>
```

D) all done.

Comment: Worth mentioning, this is for a Spreadsheet Add-on, while Sandy's answer is for a standalone script.